Move C# Project (.csproj file, folders & code files) to a different physical folder within same solution directory?
I accidentally created a project in the root folder of my solution i.e. .\Myproject\Myproject.csproj rather than .\src\Myproject\Myproject.csproj.
How do I move it to the .\src\ directory? There's no option to do so in Jetbrains Rider.
I tried moving them in Explorer, and that broke my solution.
Workaround: Created new project in the correct folder, then copied over the files and wrestled the dependencies into place. Inelegant, irritating, got the job done.
Very annoying there isn't a standard way to do this.

After moving the files you can remove and re-add the project to the solution.

If it's freshly created, I'd delete it (in IDE and external) and then create it again at the correct spot. If you created a new git branch to add it - just revert and start over.

@David I can't find the option to add a project

@Fildor it's not freshly created, sadly, there was quite some work done in it

I don't know that IDE but most likely you can edit the solution file in a text editor to update the project path

@KileKasmirAsmussen: In Visual Studio one would just right-click on the solution and there's an option to add a new or existing project.  If your IDE doesn't have that, the option may exist somewhere else but it seems like a pretty unintuitive interface.  Worst case, you can open the .sln file in a text editor and manually update the file system paths as needed.

^^ Right click on the solution, then "Edit" -> "Edit 'WhatEverYourSolution.sln"
